# Long IRQs OFF for _raw_spin_lock_irqsave

Tags: linux, real-time, scheduler, trace

I am trying to rectify some strange behavior of my Linux system for quite some time and I am stuck. So I would like to humbly ask for any advice of people who understand Linux kernel guts better than me.

I have a kernel 4.9.68 with PREEMPT_RT running on iMX7 MCU. I have PROVE_LOCKING set, which has detected some gpio_lock inconsistency in a driver, which I am going to fix - this is not an issue.

The problem is, when I run cyclictest, I get huge jitter maximum of several milliseconds. But the strange thing is, that the systems starts to behave correctly as soon as I invoke the gpio_lock inconsistency warning by triggering the faulty driver IRQ or turn the PROVE_LOCKING feature off.

The preemptirqsoff tracer says that there are long IRQs OFF sections caused by _raw_spin_lock_irqsave. The comment in the [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.68/source/include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h#L100) says that the function is non-preemptible when lockdep is used. So I suspect the PROVE_LOCKING option is not suitable for RT system and should be turnd off.

But I am not satisfied with such solution, because I don't understand two things:

1. Why is the problem gone once the gpio_lock is (dis)proved?
2. Why it persists even when the faulty driver is disabled?

Or what detail is missing in my understanding of the system?

I haven't seen any pattern in function_graph trace that would give me any clue.

I would really appreciate any direction, hint or blame for my misunderstanding :)

Comment: `"this is not an issue"` I think I've heard that before.  Anyway, nice summary.  If you ever have an issue, please post your code and then we can offer some help.  Maybe there is a longer path with ints disabled than you think.  Trying to reason about a bug with an unknown cause can be futile.

Comment: The problem is in the ads7846 driver, which is not compatible with PREEMPT_RT, because it is using legacy gpio integer interface.

Its IRQ handler through [get_pendown](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.68/source/drivers/input/touchscreen/ads7846.c#L608), through gpio_get_value will eventually call the gpio_to_desc, which tries to spin_lock the gpio_lock in the IRQ context->which is a problem with PREEMPT_RT.

Comment: So the cause of the lock inconsistency is known, however I would expect it, if beeing the troublemaker, to cause problems all the time, not only until disproved by the lockdep. Also the problematic piece of code is not invoked at all while the high latencies are measured.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with just disabling the PROVE_LOCKING option. Still don't know why is this happening, but it just disappears once this feature is disabled. So either there is a bug somewhere in the module or it is desired but undocumented behaviour...

Nevertheless the latency monitoring of OSADL QA Farm (e.g. [this one](https://www.osadl.org/Profile-of-system-in-rack-7-slot-8.qa-profile-r7s8.0.html?shadow=1)) have it disabled as well, so I think they know what they are doing and I am fine with that.

Thanks to everyone who has spent time by reading and thinking about my issue.